# USB Debug mode disconnects Samsung device in Windows 8.1

Tags: usb, windows-8.1

Until today, my Samsung S5360 phone has worked okay with a Windows 8.1 computer.

Today, it is not recognized by the computer.

IF I disable USB debug in the phone AND reconnect another USB device in another USB slot, it is recognized *as mass storage*.
At the moment, when I enable USB debug, it is disconnected for the computer.

I have KIES installed, it didn't help. I uninstalled it, and my phone was re-recognized as mass storage, but enabling USB immediately kills the connection.

What should I do to see my phone again?

Answer (score 0):

That is quite strange. Try uninstalling all samsung software and drivers and reboot. After that plug your device back up and let windows find it again. Try a different cable and also check if your port might be damaged. I had similar issues with my galaxy note and using the original cord was the fix. On some samsungs, 3rd party cords dont connect as well sometimes.

Comment: I did all what you suggested. It seems there is absolutely no connection between the phone and the computer. In device manager, in Other devices, it is not visible. Any other computer, it is recognized correctly. I don't want to _reinstall Windows_ because of a driver (or software) malfunction.

Comment: I completely understand and agree....if you have another hard drive or want to shrink your windows partition down and install a second copy of windows for testing, thats what i would do at this point. You said that you have to plug in the phone...AND THEN another device for it to show up as a mass storage device. This can indicate a hardware malfunction either in your ports or in the usb controller. And i'm sure you have tried all the ports by now....another parallel windows install will tell if its hardware or software

Comment: I tested the phone in another computer, and it recognized it well. I get another phone (an old Sony), and it is recognized and can be used with USB debug. So it definitely is driver related. It seems that my Windows 8.1 had enough of the Samsung driver...

Comment: Ok hmm...if it is properly (completely) removed and then reinstalled then it should work...you might need to research if theres a samsung software removal tool somewhere. Or when you uninstall it in dev mgr, make sure to tick the delete driver checkbox